# Handle OnBackPress from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have 3 fragments Fragment1, Fragment2 and Fragment3 and navigation is like

> Fragment1->Fragment2->Fragment3

But on back press From Fragment3 go back to Fragment2 after completing some task like from Fragment2. And from Fragment1 finish this activity.

what will be the best method to do this task.

Comment: Try to create two methods in activity. In one view pager item++ and in second view pager item-- . use this methods in fragment back pressed accordingly.

Comment: some good answers here for what you're after (I think!) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930501/back-navigation-with-fragments-toolbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your question just you have to add `addToBackStack()` method before `commit()` transaction.

for example:

```
FirstFragment firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.article_fragment, firstFragment)
    .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Add second and third fragment same as above manner and just add code in `onBackPressed()` Override method.

for example:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can i check Fragment instance by getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentBYId(id) inside onBackPress?

Comment: In fact, you may need to visit this answer of GoodLife on (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340303/in-fragment-on-back-button-pressed-activity-is-blank/20340492)

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the process. 
 1. When you add fragment add below code to your code

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

2. Then back button handle from the activity.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
   if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()>0){
       getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
   }else {
       super.onBackPressed();
   } }
   ```

It will be working perfectly. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to handle `OnBackPress` inside `Fragment`. When you performing `Fragment` transaction, you can put your fragment to `BackStack`:

> When there are FragmentTransaction objects on the back stack and the user presses the Back button, the FragmentManager pops the most recent transaction off the back stack and performs the reverse action (such as removing a fragment if the transaction added it).

More details you can get from this [article](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments).